# Line break in formula

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I have a math, that is too long for only one line. Now I want it to break like this:

```
f(x) = 
    x + ...
```

Or what is the mathematic right way to break such a long formula into several line?

Thanks for your help!!

P.S.: Its not an equation like

```
 f(x) = x + ...
      = ....
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `multline` environment of the `amsmath` package?

Comment: No, because I'm new at LaTeX.. But I'll look it up right now.. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

The amsmath package provides "split" see http://www.tug.org/teTeX/tetex-texmfdist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf, page 3 ff.

A nice example can be found on http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=3916